# Fire an event for specific record in an iteration list

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, ui

I use aura:iteration to display a chatter feed from a group in a lightning page. For each feed, I have a button "Share" which on click should Open/Close up a div part(or only for the feed item) in the component.I have created an event for onclick but still, it is not triggering specifically for the feed but triggers for all the feeds.Below is the part of the code. I want to understand what I need to do here now..

> Component

```
<aura:component access="global" controller="ChatterFeedController">
<aura:attribute name="groupattid" type="String" /> 
<aura:attribute name="groupatt" type="String[]" />
<aura:attribute name="sharing" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="shar" type="String"/>
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.userFeedItem}" value="{!this}"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="selectShareFeedEventFired" type="c:selectShareFeed" /> 
<aura:handler name="selectShareFeedEventFired" event="c:selectShareFeed" action="{!c.setFeed}"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.groupatt}" var="feed" >
<li class="slds-col slds-item slds-m-right--medium">
            <a href="" onclick="{!c.sharetoggle}" type="button" data-feedid="{!feed.id}" title="Share this item" class="FontFeedFooter slds-post__footer-action"> 
               <lightning:icon iconName="utility:share"  size="small"  alternativeText="Share this item"/><b>Share</b>
            </a>
        <div class="slds-col slds-item slds-m-right--medium">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.sharing}">
              <div class="slds-publisher slds-publisher--discussion" aura:id="{!feed.id}">
                <label for="comment-text-input2" class="slds-assistive-text">Share the Feed</label>
                <textarea id="comment-text-input2" class="Font slds-publisher__input slds-textarea slds-text-longform"
                 placeholder="Share it with, @.. "></textarea>
                <div class="slds-publisher__actions slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread">
                  <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand">Share</button>
                </div>
             </div>
            </aura:if> 
       </div> 
</li>
</aura:iteration>
```

> Event

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Event template" >
<aura:attribute name="shar" type="String"/>
</aura:event>
```

> Controller

```
 userFeedItem: function(component, event, helper) {
    var userFeed = component.get("c.getFeedData");
    var groupID = component.get("v.groupattid");
    userFeed.setParams({"groupId" : groupID});
    userFeed.setCallback(this,function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
        if(state==="SUCCESS"){
           var jtext     = response.getReturnValue();
           var FeedAtt   = component.get("v.groupatt");
    for (var i=0; i<jtext.elements.length; ++i){ 
      //the feed response in JSON format pushed to FeedAtt variable 
      FeedAtt.push(jtext.elements[i]);
      component.set("v.groupatt",FeedAtt);

    } 

        } else {
            console.log('Problem getting feed, response state: ' + state);
        }    
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(userFeed);
},



sharetoggle : function(component, event, helper) {
              console.log("Inside sharetoggle");
  var feedID = event.currentTarget.dataset.feedid;
  var shared = component.get("v.sharing");
              console.log("got attribute v.sharing-->"+shared+feedID);
  var selectShareFeed = component.getEvent("selectShareFeed");
              console.log("got SelectEvent-->"+selectShareFeed);
  selectShareFeed.setParams({ 
                     "shar": shared
                     });
  selectShareFeed.fire();
  console.log("Inside Share function, Feed Id-->"+feedItemID);
  //component.set("v.sharing",!component.get("v.sharing"));
},


setFeed: function(component, event, helper) {
               console.log("Inside Set Feed");
        var selected = event.getParam("shar");
        component.set("v.sharing",!selected);
  },
```

Comment: You've specified an APPLICATION level event; this will cause it to fire off to every component in the page. At minimum, change the event type to COMPONENT instead. This should prevent it from going everywhere. You haven't shared your iteration component, so I can't say if additional changes would be necessary, but this should get you started.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have marked the event type as COMPONENT. Also, I had to add the Name attribute to the Event handler as it was not allowing me to save without it. But now, the "SelectEvent" is not being handled by the component and hence nothing happens onclick. I have modified the code to show the iterating component

Comment: @sfdcfox . I had to modify the sharetoggle  function slightly  but atleast it is now being handled.. But it still doesn't  trigger for the specific feed and is firing for every component. I believe  some changes need to be done for the iterating component but I just can't figure out what they are..

Comment: Give me a moment; I think I've got an example here somewhere... I write a lot of code though, so it might take me a moment to find it.